# Converting different date formats to new Date() then seeing if date1 is between date2 and date3

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html5 / javascript application where I read text files and create different arrays.

For example:

variables in my LDate array have values like this: 03/13/2016

variables in my TDate array have values like this: 15 Feb 16-26 Mar 16

When I am reading my text files, it would be easy to convert "03/13/2015" and "15 Feb 16-26 Mar 16" using

```
     var d = new Date(2016, 2, 13)
     var d1 = new Date(2016, 1, 16)
     var d2 = new Date(2016, 2, 26)
```

Then I want to see if d is between d1 and d2, so I thought about using:

```
    if (d.valueOf > d1.valueOf & d.valueOf < d1.valueOf)
    {alert{"d is between d1 and d2")}
```

I did a quick test and this seemed to work.

Is this a decent way to approach this problem?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might observed that people use getTime(). As per the following documentation, you can use valueOf as well.

---

The getTime() method returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time.

You can use this method to help assign a date and time to another Date object. This method is functionally equivalent to the valueOf() method.

---